# Why does Android 10 and Android 9 LocationsSettingsRequest return different results

Tags: android, kotlin, location, android-location

I was developing an app and tested it on Android 9 and all was good.
One week ago I updated my phone to Android 10 and noticed that the app that I develop start working in the wrong way. I checked again on Android 9 and it's ok, but new Android 10 is not working as expected.

The problem related with location:

1. I ask location permission (using Dexter)

```
Dexter.withActivity(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).withListener(object : PermissionListener {
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                override fun onPermissionGranted(response: PermissionGrantedResponse?) {
                    Timber.d("onPermissionGranted [%s]", response?.permissionName)
                    turnOnLocation(OnSuccessListener {
                        requestLocation()
                    })
                }

                override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(permission: PermissionRequest?, token: PermissionToken?) {
                    Timber.d("onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown")
                    token?.continuePermissionRequest()
                }

                override fun onPermissionDenied(response: PermissionDeniedResponse?) {
                    Timber.d("onPermissionDenied [%s]", response?.permissionName)
                }
            }).check()
```

2. When permission is granted I tried turn on location

```
private fun turnOnLocation(onSuccessListener: OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>? = null) {
        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest).setAlwaysShow(true)
        val locationSettings = settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())

        onSuccessListener?.let { locationSettings.addOnSuccessListener(it) }
        locationSettings.addOnFailureListener {
            if (it is ResolvableApiException) it.startResolutionForResult(this@MainActivity, requestCheckSettings)
        }
    }
```

3. Then I wait for activity result here:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == requestCheckSettings) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Timber.i("GPS enabled")
                requestLocation()
            } else {
                Timber.e("GPS is not enabled")
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally:

> Blockquote

In ANDROID 10:
After click on "OK" in "Turn On location" dialog - app navigate me to unexpected behavior
`Timber.e("GPS is not enabled")`

> Blockquote

In ANDROID 9:
After click on "OK" in "Turn On location" dialog - app navigate me to the expected behavior
`Timber.i("GPS enabled")`

Does anyone have thoughts about this?

Comment: Do you have some answers on this?